# How can I make a json file available for download using vue.js and webpack?

Tags: json, vue.js, webpack, vue-loader

I'm building a simple card component in vue.js containing three buttons. Each button downloads a different file with different extensions each: CSV, XLSX, and JSON. So far I was able to make the first two buttons work correctly but I'm having a hard time making the JSON file downloadable.

Here's the template I'm using:

```
<template>
  <div>
   <b-button :href="require('../assets/data/File.csv')" download> CSV </b-button>
   <b-button :href="require('../assets/data/File.xlsx')" download> XLSX </b-button>
   <b-button :href="require('../assets/data/File.json')" download> JSON </b-button>    
  </div>  
</template>
```

And this is my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
      config.module.rule('downloads')
        .test(/\.(json|xlsx?|csv|pptx?)(\?.*)?$/)
        .use('file-loader')
        .loader('file-loader')
        .options({ name: 'downloads/[name].[hash:6].[ext]' })
    },  
}
```

The console indicates me the following error regarding the JSON file url:

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "href". Expected String with value "[object Object]..." got Array
```

I've already tried using `json-loader` but the result is the same.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Webpack has native handling for JSON files so I'd imagine you need a way to bypass that and use the file-loader. I'm looking around but haven't found much yet ~ https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6586 and https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/issues/259

Comment: Thanks Phil, apparently some people resolved this by adding `type: 'javascript/auto'` into `webpack.config.js`. I'm using `webpack-chain` and passed the `type` rule as an option but it didn't work.